# Using Django, how to count amount of free shelf space using a queryset?

Tags: django, django-queryset

Im developing an inventory management web app that allows teams, within an organisation, to be assigned boxes to store things in.

There are multiple storage rooms and multiple shelves and sections. Every box is assigned a project.

[image]

I would like to write a queryset in Django that shows how many empty spaces there are in a given room (how many locations there are that do not have boxes assigned to them) e.g. for the above picture showing room A

Room: A
Empty Spaces: 4

Here is a simplified version of my code:

HTML:

```
{% for each_space in Room_data %}

{
<p>"Room": "Room {{each_space.loc_room}}",</p>
<p>"Empty Spaces": *** HERE I NEED HELP ***,</p>
},
{% endfor %}
```

Model:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    loc_room = models.CharField()
    loc_section = models.IntegerField()
    loc_shelf = models.CharField()


class Box(models.Model):
    box_contents = models.CharField() 
    project_assigned_to = models.ForeignKey()
    Location = models.OneToOneField()

class Project(models.Model):
    project_name = models.CharField()
    project_manager = models.ForeignKey()
```

Views:

```
def dashboard(request):
    Room_data = Location.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'main_app/dashboard.html' , {"Room_data":Room_data})
```

I've been stuck on this for a lot of today so I was hoping somebody might know the best direction forward. Thank you in advance.

Comment: If the `Box` is removed, then the `Location` is still in the table, right?

Comment: Yes, thats correct Willem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain a list of locations with no `Box` with:

```
Location.objects.filter(box__isnull=True)
```

or even simpler:

```
Location.objects.filter(box=None)
```

We can obtain a `QuerySet` with such `Location`s for a given room `some_room` with:

```
Location.objects.filter(box=None, loc_room=some_room)
```

This will result in a query that looks like:

```
SELECT location.*
FROM location
LEFT OUTER JOIN box ON location.id = box.Location_id
WHERE box.id IS NULL
AND   location.loc_room = some_room
```

we can also count the number of `Location`s with:

```
Location.objects.filter(box=None, loc_room=some_room).count()
```

If you want to retrieve *per* room the number of empty locations, we can annotate these, like:

```
Location.objects.values(
    'loc_room'
).filter(
    box__isnull=True
).annotate(
    nempty=Count('id')
).order_by('loc_room')
```

Then we can print these like:

```
{% for each_space in Room_data %}
<p>"Room": "Room {{ each_space.loc_room }}",</p>
<p>"Empty Spaces": {{ each_space.nempty }},</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Ah! But what would my HTML refer to in '"Empty Spaces": {{  }} as it does not work when I try {{each_space.count}}?

Comment: @RickDekkard: shouldn't this be `{{ Room_data.count }}`?

Comment: You're right! My Bad! Thank you! I'm trying this now :)

Comment: Willem, I may not be understanding you properly: With the loc_room=some_room occurring in the views, how do I iterate per room in a query from the HTML? If that makes sense? I'm adding some more information and graphics to the question that might help